# using jsonschema2pojo only creates List<Object>, nothing more complex

Tags: java, jsonschema2pojo

I'm trying to use jsonschema2pojo to generate java objects, but my array of objects is just producing a `List<Object>` not a new, mapped object.  Is there a config setting I need to provide?

In the below example, I was expecting an `OtherLanguages` POJO, and a `public List<Object> otherLanguages;` field.

example JSON:

```json
{
    "firstName": "testfirst",
    "lastName": "testlast",
    "birthCountry": {
        "value": 3,
        "label": "Afghanistan (AF)"
    },
    "otherLanguages": [{
            "value": 218,
            "label": "Uzbek (UZB)"
        },
        {
            "value": 216,
            "label": "Ukrainian (UKR)"
        }
    ]
}
```

resulting schema (generated using https://jsonschema.net):

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "type": "object",
    "title": "The root schema",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "$id": "#/properties/firstName",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "The firstName schema"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "$id": "#/properties/lastName",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "The lastName schema"
        },
        "birthCountry": {
            "$id": "#/properties/birthCountry",
            "type": "object",
            "title": "The birthCountry schema",
            "properties": {
                "value": {
                    "$id": "#/properties/birthCountry/properties/value",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "title": "The value schema"
                },
                "label": {
                    "$id": "#/properties/birthCountry/properties/label",
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "The label schema"
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "otherLanguages": {
            "$id": "#/properties/otherLanguages",
            "type": "array",
            "title": "The otherLanguages schema",
            "items": {
                "$id": "#/properties/otherLanguages/items",
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "$id": "#/properties/otherLanguages/items/anyOf/0",
                        "type": "object",
                        "title": "The first anyOf schema",
                        "properties": {
                            "value": {
                                "$id": "#/properties/otherLanguages/items/anyOf/0/properties/value",
                                "type": "integer",
                                "title": "The value schema"
                            },
                            "label": {
                                "$id": "#/properties/otherLanguages/items/anyOf/0/properties/label",
                                "type": "string",
                                "title": "The label schema"
                            }
                        },
                        "additionalProperties": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

generated POJOs (from the http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ site, no options selected)

```java
-----------------------------------com.example.BirthCountry.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;


/**
* The birthCountry schema
* <p>
*
*
*/
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"value",
"label"
})
public class BirthCountry {

/**
* The value schema
* <p>
*
*
*/
@JsonProperty("value")
public Integer value;
/**
* The label schema
* <p>
*
*
*/
@JsonProperty("label")
public String label;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;


/**
* The root schema
* <p>
*
*
*/
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"firstName",
"lastName",
"birthCountry",
"otherLanguages"
})
public class Example {

/**
* The firstName schema
* <p>
*
*
*/
@JsonProperty("firstName")
public String firstName;
/**
* The lastName schema
* <p>
*
*
*/
@JsonProperty("lastName")
public String lastName;
/**
* The birthCountry schema
* <p>
*
*
*/
@JsonProperty("birthCountry")
public BirthCountry birthCountry;
/**
* The otherLanguages schema
* <p>
*
*
*/
@JsonProperty("otherLanguages")
public List<Object> otherLanguages = null;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Array Validation to `First` when creating JSON Schema, then it will become a strict object.

[See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpG5v.png)

Comment: Yes!  Ok, that fixed it.  I knew I must have been missing a config option.  So, the problem was that `AnyOf` meant the property could be populated with different types, so the generator had no choice but to make it an `Object`.